# SQL loop get a null value

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, select, cursor

In the next portion of code i used a cursor and a loop to generate a list of users who match the search query,
but i get a `null` value, why ?

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE ids TEXT;
    DECLARE response TEXT;
    DECLARE ids_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id 
        FROM user WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
        OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
        OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%');
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 2;

    OPEN ids_cursor;
    get_ids: LOOP

        FETCH ids_cursor INTO ids;

        IF finished = 2 THEN
            LEAVE get_ids;
        END IF;

        SET response = CONCAT(ids,";",response);

    END LOOP get_ids;
    CLOSE ids_cursor;

    RETURN response;
END
```

Comment: Are you getting `wrong result` or `Error`

Comment: Yes , i am getting a null result!

Comment: i call the function with `select name_of_function('test') as response; `

Comment: are you sure the query is succeeding? try set response to 'not foudn' or similar in the IF finished=2 block to debug that.

Comment: also, you can do this with GROUP_CONCAT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use user defined function you can direcltly fetch the IDs using [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function by below query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ';') AS response
FROM user 
WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
   OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%') 
   OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%');
```